# Not printing file contents

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to read and print the contents of a text file, but nothing shows up:

```
coffee = open('coffeeInventory.txt' , 'r')
coffee.seek(0)
line = coffee.readline()
while line != '':
    print(line)
    
coffee.close()
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You only read one line. If you want to read more than one line, put readline into the loop, or use readlines() to grab them all.

Comment: Do your file have content? try cat and print

Comment: If you don't need to do any processing, you can just do one line: `print(open('coffeeInventory.txt').read())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('coffeeInventory.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        print(line, end='')
```

`readline` leaves a newline on the end of the line, so use `end=''` to prevent `print` from appending its own newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for each line, please:

```
file = open('coffeeInventory.txt') 
lines = file.readlines()         
for line in lines:
    print(line)
file.close()
```